# What is the functional way to properly set a dependent predicate for Observable sequence without side effect?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have three observables `oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved`, `oGotFocus` and `oLostFocus`. I would like `oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved` to push sequences only when `_active` is true. My implementation below works as needed, but it introduces a side-effect on `_active`. Is there anyway to remove side-effect but still get the same functionality?

```
class TestClass
{
  private bool _active = true;

  public TestClass(..)
  {
    ...

    var oLostFocus = Observable
      .FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_view, "LostFocus")
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    var oGotFocus = Observable
      .FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_view, "GotFocus")
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    var oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved = oDocumentSaved // some other observable
      .Merge<CustomEvtArgs>(oGotFocus)
      .Where(_ => _active)
      .Publish();

    var lostFocusDisposable = oLostFocus.Subscribe(_ => _active = false);
    var gotFocusDisposable  = oGotFocus.Subscribe(_ => _active = true);

    // use case
    oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved.Subscribe(x => DoSomethingWith(x));
    ...

  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: Do you mean here? `oLostFocus.Subscribe (_ => _active = false)`. If so, since `_active` won't change `oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved` will always fire the event, which is not what I want. My end use case (see in code) is `oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved`'s subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound like you really want a `oDocumentSavedWhenHasFocus` rather than a `oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved` observable.

So try using the `.Switch()` operator, like this:

```
var oDocumentSavedWhenHasFocus =
    oGotFocus
        .Select(x => oDocumentSaved.TakeUntil(oLostFocus))
        .Switch();
```

This should be fairly obvious as to how it works, once you know how `.Switch()` works.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't TakeUntil signal `OnCompleted` when `oLostFocus` starts pushing its sequences? I would like this observable to continue until the view is disposed.

Comment: Yes, and that causes the inner observable to complete, but then the next time that `oGotFocus` is raised, a brand new inner observable is projected, to which `Switch` subscribes, thus the outer observable never completes.  This is yet another way to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of SelectMany and TakeUntil should get you where you need to be.

```
from g in oGotFocus
from d in oDocumentSaved
          .Merge<CustomEvtArgs>(oGotFocus)
          .TakeUntil(oLostFocus)
```

Comment: Doesn't `TakeUntil` signal `onCompleted` when `oGotFocus` starts? I would like this observable to run till the application ends while only switching on/off depending on if the view has focus or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to be notified when the document is saved, but only if the document currently has focus.  Correct?  (And you also want to be notified when the document gets focus, but that can easily be merged in later.)

Think in terms of *windows* instead of *point* events; i.e., join by coincidence.

Your requirement can be represented as a `Join` query whereby *document saves* are joined to *focus windows*, thus yielding notifications only when both overlap; i.e., when both are "active".

```
var oGotFocusOrDocumentSaved = 
  (from saved in oDocumentSaved
   join focused in oGotFocus
   on Observable.Empty<CustomEventArgs>()  // oDocumentSave has no duration
   equals oLostFocus // oGotFocus duration lasts until oLostFocus
   select saved)
   .Merge(oGotFocus);
```